# mosquitto broker to integrate with mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mqtt

I am using an eclipse paho client to send  mqtt messages to a mosquitto broker. The payload is in JSON format. The broker parses the payload and updates it with some more information and publishes to a subscriber. The subscriber in my case is a BDAS/SPARK instance.

the client, broker and SPARK instance are running in different boxes.
in this sequence i want to integrate my mosquitto broker with mongoDB..i tried to do it with nodered but not successful.

Could you point me to some suggestion on this ?

Comment: What was your problem with node red? It should be pretty trivial to take a topic and store it in a collection

Comment: i was able to add a node for mqtt in node red.in mqtt control box i gave my broker address  as "<IP>:1883". when i clicked deploy it says 'no response from server'

Comment: There is a separate box for the port number (1883), you should not have needed to include the port in the broker address field. You should be able to get help with configuring Node-Red from the mailing list here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red

Answer (score 3):

If mosquitto is not a hard requirement, you could also use a MQTT broker with a plugin system (like HiveMQ) to do this. You can see an example architecture in [this blog post](http://www.hivemq.com/mqtt-sql-database/).

It should be pretty trivial to write such a plugin for HiveMQ, you only need to implement the *OnPublishCallback* (see [the documentation](http://www.hivemq.com/docs/plugins/2.0.0/#onPublish-callback))

An example where you can start is e.g. [This Github Repository](https://github.com/hivemq/hivemq-database-example-plugin).